# wrapping std::packaged_task inside a custom class

Tags: c++, c++11, packaged-task

I'm trying to wrap std::packaged_task inside another class in order to be used together with a task scheduler.

At the moment I got it all working except std::future support. To get std::future support I figured out I need to use std::packaged_task for the get_future() function that it provides.

I've been trying whole day all sorts of ways to get this to work, but I seem to be unable to properly declare and initialise the packaged_task using the return value from a std::bind. I have tried to decipher the implementations of all the related libstdc++ functions such as std::async, std::future, std::thread etc but with no luck.

The following code is the implementation of both the not working version and the working one. To get it to work uncomment the two /* --- WORKS*/ and comment the other related line.

```
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>

#include <windows.h>

class task
{
private:
    struct task_implementation_base
    {
        virtual void execute() = 0;
    };

    template <class callable>
    struct task_implementation : public task_implementation_base
    {
        task_implementation(callable&& f) : /*m_task(std::forward<callable>(f)) WORKS*/m_task(f) { }
        void execute() { m_task(); }

        //callable m_task; // WORKS
        std::packaged_task<typename result_of<callable>::type> m_task;
    };

    template <class callable>
    std::shared_ptr<task_implementation<callable>> make_routine(callable&& f)
    {
        return std::make_shared<task_implementation<callable>>(std::forward<callable>(f));
    }

public:
    template <class callable, class... arguments>
    task(callable&& f, arguments&&... args) : m_function(make_routine(std::bind(std::forward<callable>(f), std::forward<arguments>(args)...))) {}

    void operator()() { run(); }

    void run() { m_function->execute(); }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<task_implementation_base> m_function;

};

int testint(int i)
{
    std::cout << "test6" << " :: ran from thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
    fflush(stdout);
    return i+100;
}

void test(const char* text)
{
    std::cout << text << " :: ran from thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
    fflush(stdout);
}

class testclass
{
public:
    void print1() { test("test3"); }
    void print2() { test("test4"); }
    void print3(const char* text) { test(text); }

};

int main()
{
    testclass testclass1;
    testclass* testclass2 = new testclass;

    task test1(test, "test1");
    task test2([]() { test("test2"); });
    task test3(&testclass::print1, &testclass1);
    task test4(&testclass::print2, &*testclass2);
    task test5(&testclass::print3, &*testclass2, "test5");
    task test6(&testint, 1);

    test1();
    test2();
    test3();
    test4();
    test5();
    test6();

    Sleep(2000);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm thinking the problem is `typename result_of<callable>::type`. I'm guessing it doesn't properly evaluates to the return type of the `callable` function.

I'm using `c++ (Built by MinGW-builds project) 4.8.0 20121225 (experimental)` on a `Windows 8 64bit`. I'm suspecting the errors are irrelevant since I guess I'm just simply trying to get this work the wrong way but here is a pastebin for the errors anyway: [errors](http://pastebin.ca/2302883)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::packaged_task` not only takes the result type of the invoked function as a template argument but also the types of the arguments you are passing to the to be invoked function.

You can define them as follows:

```
// somewhere
int foo(bool, int);

// somewhere else
std::packaged_task<int(bool, int)> p(foo);
```

To fix your code you need to add two empty parenthesis pairs. What I explained above also applies to `std::result_of`.

```
std::packaged_task<typename std::result_of<callable()>::type()> m_task;
```

Comment: You're missing the point. When initialised with a std::bind(&foo, false, 0) packaged_task<int(bool, int)> turns into packaged_task<int()> because the arguments are fused into the bind.

Comment: @EdwardA That was just some random example, but if you already know the answer why are you asking then?

Comment: The code I posted doesn't compile, and I cannot figure out what the problem is and/or how to fix it. Question is, how can I do the trickery that I am doing in the working version of my code but save the function to a `std::packaged_task<????> m_task` instead of a `callable m_task` (must look at the code I posted to understand what I'm talking about).

Comment: Noticed you added the fix I needed to your answer, thank you very much good sir. All this time I've been missing two parenthesis...

Comment: @EdwardA oh and while you are checking out all the cool new C++11 features, look up the `std::chrono` library and forget that `windows.h` `Sleep` crap.

Comment: I would simplify the expression by declaring `typedef typename result_of<callable()>::type result_type;` in `task_implementation` and then use `packaged_task<result_type()>` ... it's a lot more readable!

Answer (score 0):

It is only response to main topic question. "How to implement"

Example short implementation:

```
template <typename Signature> /// <---- 1
class Task;

template <typename Res, typename... ArgTypes>
class Task<Res(ArgTypes...)>  /// <---- 2
{
public:
    template <typename Function>
    explicit Task(Function&& callback)
        : _task{std::forward<Function>(callback)}
    { }

    void execute(ArgTypes... args) noexcept(false)
    {
        //...
        _task(std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...);
    }

private:
    std::packaged_task<Res(ArgTypes...)> _task;
};
```

Not sure why step 1 & 2 are required but I did the same as in lib implementation. Maybe someone could extend this response.